# How to mock call on an attribute of class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to test the following class

```
public class MyClass {
    protected OtherClass other;
    public MyClass(String arg) {
        this.other = new OtherClass(arg);
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        String response = other.sendRequest(); // mock this call
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to test `doSomething()` and for this I need to mock the call `sendRequest()`. For this I tried the following, which did not work:

```
@Test
public void doSomethingTest() {
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass("test");
    when(myClass.other.sendRequest()).thenReturn("response");
    myClass.doSomething();
}
```

The real `sendRequest()` is still being called instead of returning the mock response.

How can I mock the call to `sendRequest()` with Mockito?

Comment: You need to inject the OtherClass object into MyClass (via constructor for example). If you instantiate the OtherClass object in the MyClass class, then it is not really possible to mock it

Comment: A classic case of dependency injection. In your original code the object that is used to call sendRequest is created outside. Your test can never access this object. You create a mock, but that mock object is never called coz the Myclass class does not even take in the mock. But if u send in the created pbject to Myclass, then in your test, u can replace the other class object with the object created in your test. This is is how dependency injection helps in tests. It allows u to replace the object going to be used in a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instantiate the `OtherClass` object in the `MyClass` class, then it is not really possible to mock it
You need to instantiate it outside of `MyClass`, and then inject it into `MyClass` (via its constructor for example).

Then all you need to do in your test is to mock the call on a mock `OtherClass` object. And use it to instantiate the `MyClass` object

Change MyClasss to be

```
public class MyClass {

    protected OtherClass other;
    
    public MyClass(OtherClass otherClass) {
        this.other = otherClass;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        String response = other.sendRequest(); 
    }

}
```

and your code will change from

```
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass("s");
```

to

```
        OtherClass other = new OtherClass("s");
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(other);
```

And you can now write this test:

```
@Test
public void doSomethingTest() {
    OtherClass other = mock(OtherClass.class);
    when(other.sendRequest()).thenReturn("response");
    
    MyClass myClass = new MyClass(other);
    myClass.doSomething();

   // .. test assertions
}
```

Comment: You might not to have to change your class MyClass. You could inherit from it in your test  by sth. like MyTestClass extends MyClass{ MyTestClass(String s){other =mock(OtherClass.class);
    when(other.sendRequest()).thenReturn("response"); } } and then you test by MyClass myClass = new MyTestClass("s");

Comment: @juwil That sounds bad to me, this is not wat inheritance is for. 
An other way might be to have a protected constructor (therefore accessible from the test) that take the OtherClass object